# SQL query to iterate over schedule job and delete it. The stored procedure will take Job_Name as Input parameter

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a problem where I get a `job_id` and job name and delete a scheduled job using a stored procedure. Here I need to pass job name as input parameter.

I am using

```
select job_id, name from msdb.dbo.sysjobs
```

and get this:

| job_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| sjkfaih | usp_1 |
| fjoajff | usp_2 |

I want to delete the stored procedure by name instead of `job_id` as it become little complex.

I want the stored procedure to take `job_name` as a parameter but return `Job_id` so that it I can execute it by using

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_id = N'@JobId', @delete_unused_schedule = 1
```

This is my attempt:

```
DECLARE @JobName nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @JobId NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE Job_ID, Job_Name CURSOR FOR
    SELECT job_id, name 
    FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs;

OPEN Job_ID, Job_Name;

FETCH NEXT FROM Job_ID, Job_Name INTO @JobId, @JobName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_id = N'@JobId', @delete_unused_schedule = 1

    FETCH NEXT FROM Job_ID INTO @JobId;
END

CLOSE Job_ID;
DEALLOCATE Job_ID;
```

I think I am doing something wrong as I am getting a syntax error. Please suggest me some improvements. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your cursor a **valid name** - not a list of columns ....

Try this code:

```
DECLARE @JobName sysname, @JobId uniqueidentifier;

-- give your cursor a proper NAME
DECLARE JobIdNameCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT job_id, name 
    FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs;

-- open the cursor by NAME    
OPEN JobIdNameCursor;

-- fetch from cursor by NAME
FETCH NEXT FROM JobIdNameCursor INTO @JobId, @JobName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_id = N'@JobId', @delete_unused_schedule = 1;

    FETCH NEXT FROM JobIdNameCursor INTO @JobId, @JobName;
END

-- close and deallocate that cursor - again by its proper NAME
CLOSE JobIdNameCursor;
DEALLOCATE JobIdNameCursor;
```